# Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I just configured Mongoid for a Rails project, ran `rails g mongoid:config` edited my `mongoid.yml` to be like below.

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: abacus_development
      # Provides the hosts the default client can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts: 
        - localhost
      options:

test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: abacus_test
      hosts:
        - localhost
      options:
        read:
          mode: primary
        max_pool_size: 1
```

Then went on thinking everything to be running fine, to scaffold a controller and model called `Activity`. With that I ran `rails s`. The app runs fine at `localhost:3000`, but the moment I get to `localhost:3000/activites` it spits out this.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x007fbda47c4110 @tag_sets=[], @options={:database=>:abacus_development}, @server_selection_timeout=30>):
        15:   </thead>
        16:
        17:   <tbody>
        18:     <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
        19:       <tr>
        20:         <td><%= activity.amount %></td>
        21:         <td><%= activity.indicator %></td>   app/views/activities/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_activities_index_html_erb___73038992978597028_70226242222820'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running mongo right? Probably with 'mongod' if you're on a mac or 'sudo service mongod start'. Might be a stupid answer but you never know

Comment: Yeah I am. But `sudo service mongod start` doesn't work for me. I installed MongoDB using `brew install mongodb` but seemingly there might be a problem with that, since I can't even do `mongo` or `mongod` without it failing.

Comment: I solved it. I hadn't configured MongoDB correctly on my computer, and hadn't setup the launch agent, so every time I needed to use it, I needed to do `mongod` and then `mongo` simultaneously.

Comment: sudo service mongodb start

Answer (score 0):

Mongo runs on port 27017 by default, try to change your hosts configuration to localhost:27017 in your mongoid.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sudo mongod
```

I think it should work